# Adding data for specific user in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

**Firebase App**

I'm building an application where users can register/login and then access their feed.
I used authentication with email/password and that is working totally fine. Now I don't really know how can I add data to cloud firestore which is different for every user. More or less like a table/collection for each user in mongo/sql. I can create collection in cloud firestore but I don't see any option to create for specific user. Can anyone please explain me this? Or any references.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built-in for storing user-specific data in Firestore, but you can build that yourself in your application code and Firestore's server-side security rules.

You'll typically have a collection `users` for the user data, where you then have a document for each user with their data. As the ID of each document, you'll then use the UID from Firebase Authentication for that user.

This last step, makes it easy to ensure that each user only has one document, that you can easily find that document, and that each user can only write to the own document, as shown in this example in the Firebase documentation on [implementing content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).